# How would you approach string wildcards, without just comparing the correct values?

Tags: c++, regex, string, wildcard

It has come to my attention that there is no standard form of regular expressions for C++. Although there are many ways for you to check for matching values, what happens when you need complicated formula to compare one value to another, without dozens of lines just for nested IF clauses, or extremely long OR statements?

In short, how would you approach regular expressions style comparisons with C++?

EDIT: Without external libraries, I'm a bit of a newbie.

Comment: By "external libraries" I assume you mean "libraries that don't come with my compiler / OS." Can you tell us which compiler / OS combination you are using?

Comment: I use ArchLinux, and Windows for the most part. I do have access to BSD systems as well if there are any options available for it.

Comment: what compilers, including version numbers? I'm pretty sure Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 includes std::tr1::regex. I'm not sure about ArchLinux, but I know Ubuntu 10.04.2LTS provides both boost::regex and std::tr1::regex via the "apt" command.

Comment: According to [this page](http://www.archlinux.org/packages/core/i686/gcc/) gcc 4.6.0-3 on Arch Linux includes support for std::tr1::regex.

Comment: Regarding the edit: why would you not use external libraries? C++ isn't designed to have particularly rich standard libraries. You're *supposed* to extend its functionality using external libraries (preferably portable ones if you want your application to be portable). If regular expressions solve your problem, use them, although also consider implementing other useful string functions -- in eg. Python even doing a lot of string manipulation I don't use regexes much. For example a C++ function to split a string and return a vector of strings isn't very idiomatic C++ but would get the job done.

Comment: (Back when I used Perl, I used to use regexes a lot. I haven't used Perl recently, though, so I've never figured out if this was because of something about Perl, or something about the way I now program that means I'm solving similar problems fine without them).

Comment: Difficulty of installation mostly, Steve. Thanks for the info, Rob!

Comment: @Captain: in that case, Boost gives you a truckload of stuff in a single install, so it's a pretty good investment of installation effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need look no further than [Boost.Regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html), or in some modern compilers and libraries, [std::tr1::regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982727.aspx).

You may also want to consider using [Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions](http://www.pcre.org) library, PCRE.

*EDIT*: your clarification of the question to require not using any external libraries,  ultimately increases the amount of work you'll be doing.  Here is [Rob Pike's regex matching code](http://gurustop.net/blog/2008/04/27/beautiful-code-back-to-basics-please-read-this-c-code-quickly/), which may be a good start for your efforts.

Answer (score 2):

In short, [Boost.Regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) or [std::tr1::regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982727.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Check out http://www.pcre.org/.